# String handling Java/html/php

Tags: php, javascript, html

```
echo '<button class="modalInput" title="Is there an error in this question, report it here." rel="#prompt" onClick="params('.$item->catid.','.$item->id.',"'.$item->quote.'","'.$item->author.'");">';
```

Now - This Works perfectly fine - If $item->quote and $item->author doesnt hold any values like:

My uncle's house
Who said "Ich bin ein Berliner"?

Then the params string will be pretty messed up...

```
  <button class="modalInput" title="Is there an error in this question, report it here." rel="#prompt" onClick="params(21,12,"Who said "ich bin ein Berliner"","George Bush");">
```

How can I fix this?

---

Still dont Work

```
   echo '<button class="modalInput" title="Is there an error in this question, report it here." rel="#prompt" onClick="params('.$item->catid.','.$item->id.',\''.htmlspecialchars($item->quote).'\',\''.(string) htmlspecialchars($item->author).'\');">';
```

becomes

```
  <button class="modalInput" title="Is there an error in this question, report it here." rel="#prompt" onClick="params(29,29,'In a FOX TV show, what did 'The OC' stand for','Orange County');">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) function, it will encode (escape) special characters, e.g. `"` will become `&quot;`:

```
echo htmlspecialchars($item->quote);
```

Comment: No problem :) I haven't finished editing my code, so I've overriden it